# Comparing results from 2 database servers

Tags: powershell, datatable

My PowerShell script below works great and returns the two rows from different databases in 1 `DataTable`, but I can't work out how to compare these 2 rows.

The situation is I have 2 database servers, and want to compare `max(id)` from the same table on both, compare and then possibly alert if they're different.

The alerting bit I can do, but I haven't used `DataTable`s before.

```
function readServer1 {
    # Connection variables
    $server = "db1"
    $port = 1234
    $driver = "Adaptive Server Enterprise"
    $query = "select max(id) as 'id' from table"
    $db = "db"
    $uid = "uid"
    $pwd = "pwd"
    # Create Object and Connection
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "driver={$driver};db=$db;na=$server,$port;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd;"
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query, $conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 30
    # Create a Data Table
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader())
    $dt.Rows
    # Close Connection
    $conn.Close()
}

function readServer2 {
    # Connection variables
    $server = "db2"
    $port = 1234
    $driver = "Adaptive Server Enterprise"
    $query = "select max(id) as 'id' from table"
    $db = "db"
    $uid = "uid"
    $pwd = "pwd"
    # Create Object and Connection
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "driver={$driver};db=$db;na=$server,$port;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd;"
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query, $conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 30
    # Create a Data Table
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader())
    $dt.Rows
    # Close Connection
    $conn.Close()
}

readServer1 
readServer2
```

It returns results like this:

```
id
--
12345
12346
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the comparison? if you just want to know if the two results differ you can do: `if(compare $(readserver1) $(readserver2)){//different}`

Comment: I think the way i'm running it into 1 table doesn't seem to help with the compare method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put function execution results to variables and compare them. Like so:

```
$var1 = readServer1 | Select -Expand id
$var2 = readServer2 | Select -Expand id
if ($var1 -ne $var2) { Do-That }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to like that as when I set them to variables the output as `System.Data.DataRow`

Comment: @benji1304, i have edited my answer. You would want to expand property to get just the value.